# How to specify array of ENUM in liquibase?

Tags: h2, liquibase

I am trying to create a table with a column of type enum array. Sample is

```
<sql>CREATE TYPE part_state_type AS ENUM ('A','B','C','D');</sql>
<createTable tableName="parts">
   <column name="part_state" type="part_state_type []">
   </column>
</createTable>
```

When I run the migrations;  I get following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.PARTS (PART_STATE ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') [[*]]) "; expected "FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.parts (part_state ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') []) [42001-197]
```

Any idea how to create a column of type ENUM array? I am using Java 11, liquibase version is 3.5.3 and h2 version is 1.4.197. Based on this https://oliha.dev/articles/enums-as-arrays-in-postgresql/ it seems that having array of enum is possible in postgresql. So, I am not sure why is liquibase failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENUM values are broken in persistent databases in 1.4.197, this issue is fixed in later versions.

Arrays of ENUM values are broken in all versions of H2, I filled a new issue about it in the bugtracker:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2935

Note that `ENUM(something) ARRAY` syntax is only supported by current H2 and it will be supported by H2 2.0. Released versions of H2 don't have typed arrays, you can use the plain `ARRAY` data type in them, but you can run into the same issue with persisted values. In-memory database hypothetically may be not affected.